# how to get SQL-postgres to work in XEmacs 21.4.22 on windows vista

Tags: sql, emacs, xemacs, postgresql

I've previously used sql-oracle just fine in Xemacs on XP and vista.

However, now I'm using Postgresql psql on the command line but I kinda find it lame (as compared to using sql-* from within emacs)

So, I'm trying to get it(psql) working within xemacs(21.4.22) on windows. When I type

```
M-x sql-postgres ENTER, I get the following 3 prompts
User:
Database :
Server:
```

How come I am not prompted for password ? It presents a SQLi buffer but when I type my SQL in and press ENTER nothing happens. Also, I don't see any prompt (when I run psql from cmd.exe, I get the "databasename=#" prompt).
 What gives ?

What am I expected to enter in the above prompts for a DB which is running on my box(localhost) and I know which DB that I need to connect to(I know what params to give psql but not in xemacs).

I tried the same with GNU Emacs (23.1.50.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.0.6001)) and the results 
were similar : 
A SQLi buffer but none of the SQL get executed and I didn't see a prompt for password.

Thank you,

BR,
~A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, psql, like ftp, is known to not work correctly under shell-mode as it's not using the stdin, stdout handles, but a console handle.

See [Emacs FAQ for Windows / 7.2 Programs reading input hang](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/Sub_002dprocesses.html#Sub_002dprocesses)